# Why is a POST request successfully sent from the local server, but not from the production server?

Tags: django, ubuntu, post

I'm doing a project in django and I've uploaded it to a server with `gunicorn`+`nginx`. Everything works fine except my `POST` request. Infinite loading begins everytime when i try to send `POST` (and then after 30 secs the connection breaks). I have a form on the `index` page with this code:

```
<form method="post" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Consultation form">
                <div class="row row-cols-lg-3 row-cols-1 gy-lg-20 gy-10">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input class="form-control form-control-xxl text-center w-100"
                               placeholder="Your name" type="text" name="name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input class="form-control form-control-xxl text-center"
                               placeholder="Your phone"  type="tel"  required name="phone"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xxl w-100" type="submit">Get consultation
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

I also have a handler in the `views.py` file:

```
def handle_post_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        name = get_POST_parameter('name', request)
        if phone != '' and phone != None and subject != '' and subject != None:
            # Send data via HTTP POST request
            url = 'https://svarnik.ru/bx24/'
            headers = {'User-Agent': 'Reforgebot/1.0'}
            data = {
                'ikey': 'someSecretKey',
                'domain': 'example.com',
                'roistat': 'nocookie',
                'subject': subject,
                'name': name,
                'phone': phone,
            }
            try:
                response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            return redirect('index')

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        handle_post_request(request)
...
```

The strange thing is that the code works fine on the local server (`127.0.0.1:8000`) but doesnt't on ubuntu server.

I thought `redis` was screwing things up (saw that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555852/django-form-doesnt-send-post-request-and-site-freezes)), but disabling it completely and stopping it didn't help. I installed `CORS` also but nothing has changed.

I try to send fake post request on other url and it works!

Here are the `django` logs:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='svarnik.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bx24/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fdf683e6b20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```